# A method of solving differential equations - terminology

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

I have an iterative method of solving differential equations. I would like to emphasize that the method returns **approximate solutions** of differential equations. How should I call this method? I have the following ideas:

1. An iterative approximate method of solving differential equations
2. An iterative approximation method of solving differential equations
3. An iterative method of solving differential equations approximately

Which one is correct in English?

Comment: @Harry49 I would like to use the word method, and emphasize that the solution will be approximate. There are iterative methods that return exact solution. This one will not, so it is not enough to say that the method is iterative.

Comment: @Harry49 This is not bad, but the term numerical method is usually associated with methods that return approximate solutions only at certain points. My method returns an approximate polynomial solution, i.e., the solution is given in the whole interval.

Comment: @Harry49 OK, so the first option is fine? I wasn't sure about the term approximate method. I often read about approximate solutions but not approximate methods. Edit: The method has no name, it's new.

Comment: It really depends on what the method returns. For example, it would be fine in my view to include "of solving differential equations" in case it gives some terms of a Taylor series. But it would be bad to include this in case it is a certain type of iterative procedure, this is not solving anything... That is, I would say that it depends on your particular method.

Comment: @John B OK, I think that I can include  "of solving differential equations". The question is mainly about the use of the word approximate. If the first option is fine, then my problem is solved.